# Can I create unique-compound constraints on eve schema definition?

Tags: python, mongodb, eve, cerberus

I would like to know if it is possible to create a unique constraint into an `eve` schema definition, between two or more fields of a document, instead of only one as shown on Eve's [schema definition documentation](http://python-eve.org/config.html#schema-definition),

I want the same behavior as creating a [Unique Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index) directly on `mongodb`, but on the `eve` API level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not supported. However, Eve will respond with a `409 Conflict` and a [proper message in the response body](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/io/mongo/mongo.py#L442) if a duplicate key error is returned by Mongo, no matter wether the `unique` rule has been set at the API level.